# Get current users access token from Firebase in React Native

Tags: firebase, api, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the Firebase authentication access token within a React Native application so that I can authenticate my API calls to a custom server. The Firebase documentation says I should get this token by using `auth().currentUser.getIdToken();` however currentUser returns `null`.

I've tried to use `getIdToken()` in multiple areas of the application. I know the access token is generated as I can see it in the logs while using expo (user.stsTokenManager.accessToken).

Why is `currentUser` returning `null` and how can I get the `accessToken`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to wrap `user.getIdToken()` inside of `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` for `user` to be available. You can then use jwtToken in your header to authenticate your API calls. You need to import your Firebase configuration file for this to work.

```
let jwtToken = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {  // <------ Check this line
          alert(idToken); // It shows the Firebase token now
          return idToken;
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: How do i pass the idToken to a function? seem to be getting null.

Comment: Having the same issue. How do I pass the idToken to a separate function that holds my API call?

Comment: Just call the function before `return` statement or `set it in a state` then pass to any function or use `then() `

Answer (score 1):

Just putting `await` before will work too just like this:

> `await auth().currentUser.getIdToken();`

Answer (score 0):

> `getIdToken` returns a promise

```js
firebase.auth()
        .signInWithCredential(credential)
        .then(async data => {
          const jwtToken = await data.user?.getIdToken();
          console.log(jwtToken);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

## Hook example

Unfortunately, its not reliable to directly get the token. You first have to listen to the authentication state change event which fires upon initialization since its asynchronous.

```js
import {auth} from '../utils/firebase'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function useToken() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    return auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        user.getIdToken(true)
        .then(latestToken => setToken(latestToken))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
    })
  }, [])
  return token
}
```

then use like so in your functional component

```js
const token = useToken()

useEffect(() => {
  if (token) {
    // go wild
  }
}, [token])
```