# Firebase Authentication issue for using the accessToken

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase Authentication in my react app. After successful authentication i need to pass the accessToken to my Backend in each api call, so that backend can verify for a valid token. But the issue I am facing is when I am in my home page and try to reload the page, i have written a useEffect which will call my `user details` api. but here when I try `auth1.currentUser?.getIdToken(true)`, it will come as null. or if i try like below the api call is getting called even before getting the user details

```
useEffect(() =>{
const auth1 = getAuth();
   const token = auth1.onAuthStateChanged(async (user: any) => {
   console.log({user});
   const idToken = await user?.getIdToken();
   console.log('authToken', {idToken});
   return localStorage.getItem('token');
  });
//api call for userdetails
},[])
```

could someone give how example of how the flow should be?
this scenario can happen for me from all of my pages reload

Comment: Have you seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68749347/17963017 ? If it helps, close this question.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to **reload the page**, I have written a useEffect which will call
> my user details API. But here when I try
> `auth1.currentUser?.getIdToken(true)`, it will come as `null`.

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), if you reload the page, the Auth object may be in "an intermediate state, such as initialization".

You should use an observer on the Auth object (with the `onAuthStateChanged()` method) to get the current user, as explained in the same doc.